# How to add FlowException inside Flow in Corda?

Tags: corda

I am trying to add FlowException inside Corda Flow.

I have added the following part in my code. This is always true. I just want to display the message "Trade id already available"

```
 val a : Int = 10
            val b : Int = 10

            if (a == b){
                throw FlowException("Trade id already available")
            }
```

When i run the code, since Flows end pre-maturely due to exceptions, it should dispays the Flow exception error. But only thing it is doing is ending the flow not displaying the message

[image: This is how flow is ending]

My complete code is:

```
object ExampleFlow {
    @InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    class Initiator(val iouValue: Int,
                    val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {



        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
            // Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
            val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

            val a : Int = 10
            val b : Int = 10

            if (a == b){
                throw FlowException("Trade id already available")
            }


            val iouState = IOUState(iouValue, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherParty)
            val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), iouState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
            val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                    .addOutputState(iouState, IOUContract.ID)
                    .addCommand(txCommand)


            txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)


            val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)


            val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty)
            val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(otherPartySession), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))


            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, setOf(otherPartySession), FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
        }
    }

    @InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
    class Acceptor(val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
            val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartySession) {
                override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                    val output = stx.tx.outputs.single().data
                    "This must be an IOU transaction." using (output is IOUState)
                    val iou = output as IOUState
                    "I won't accept IOUs with a value over 100." using (iou.value <= 100)
                }
            }
            val txId = subFlow(signTransactionFlow).id

            return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession, expectedTxId = txId))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me, I used the same code as yours:

```kotlin
@Suspendable
override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
    // Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
    val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

    val a : Int = 10
    val b : Int = 10

    if (a == b){
        throw FlowException("Trade id already available")
    }

    // Stage 1.
    progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
    // Generate an unsigned transaction.
    val iouState = IOUState(iouValue, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherParty)
    val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), iouState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
    val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
            .addOutputState(iouState, IOUContract.ID)
            .addCommand(txCommand)

    // Stage 2.
    progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
    // Verify that the transaction is valid.
    txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

    // Stage 3.
    progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
    // Sign the transaction.
    val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

    // Stage 4.
    progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
    // Send the state to the counterparty, and receive it back with their signature.
    val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty)
    val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(otherPartySession), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))

    // Stage 5.
    progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
    // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.
    return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, setOf(otherPartySession), FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
}
```

Here's the node shell:

[image]

Comment: What might be the reason for this? It is not just this project, i am facing the same issue in my different project. Flow is prematurely ending if it not meeting certain conditions but it not throwing flowexception message.

Comment: Since you based your flow on the `ExampleFlow` of the `cordapp-example`; I recommend that you start all over, meaning copy/paste the sample code of the flow into your `ExmapleFlow` file, run the flow in the shell (to make sure that the code works properly and you didn't miss anything); then add the line that throws the exception and run the flow again to see what happens.